# Android: Set Bitmap as wallpaper

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to set a bitmap image as wallpaper. I am able to set bitmap in an ImageView. But when i try to open the intent to set it as wallpaper the app crashes. I have posted the LogCat below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = wallpaper;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap , "Title", "Description");
            if(path != null)
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(path));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Application"));
```

But i am getting this logcat error.

```
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761): Failed to insert image
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:577)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:673)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:537)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:513)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:891)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at com.shyam.flickrwallpaperapp.Wallpaper.onClick(Wallpaper.java:164)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-21 12:13:01.802: E/MediaStore(7761):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you can also set wallpaper with coding instead of intent?

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe you've ur manifest updated with below already
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>`
2. I'm copying my code here which is Camera.java for your reference

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.ImageButton;
   import android.widget.ImageView;

   public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
       ImageView iVReturnedPic;
       Button btnSetWall;
       ImageButton iBTakePic;
       static final int CameraData = 0;
       Bitmap bmap;

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.photo);
       initializePhotoVar();
       InputStream ipstr = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher) ; 
       bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ipstr);
   }
   private void initializePhotoVar() {
       iVReturnedPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iV_ReturnedPic);
       iBTakePic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iB_TakePic);
       btnSetWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_SetWall);
       btnSetWall.setOnClickListener(this);
       iBTakePic.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {
       case R.id.btn_SetWall:
           try {
               getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmap); 

           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 
            break;
       case R.id.iB_TakePic:
           Intent CamIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           startActivityForResult(CamIntent, CameraData);

           break;
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           Bundle extras = (Bundle) data.getExtras();
           bmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
           iVReturnedPic.setImageBitmap(bmap);
       }
   }
   ```

   }